# Behavior of modified Bessel function $K_n(\rho)$ near zero

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

I was able to prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $K_n(\rho)$ has the following series representation

$$K_n(\rho) = 1/2\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^m (n-m-1)!}{m!}(\rho/2)^{2m-n}+(-1)^{n-1}/2 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\rho/2)^{2m+n}}{m!(m+n)!}[2\log(\rho/2)-\psi(m+1)-\psi(m+n+1) ]$$

In the Book by N.N Lebedev and Richard R. Silverman called special functions and their applications, page 111, they say that this series representation for $K_n$ imply that when $\rho \to 0$

$$K_0(\rho)\approx \log(2/\rho)$$
$$K_n(\rho) \approx\frac{1}{2}(n-1)!(\rho/2)^{-n}\,\,\,\text{for}\,\,\, n=1,2,\dots, $$

But the book does not give the proof, and I'm trying and trying to prove this without success, I need help in finding which result the authors use to find this behaviors near zero so easily that does not even deserve a proof, I think that the behaviors above does not follow by simply calculation. Any reference on how to justify the above will be very helpful, thank you so much for the patience to read.

Comment: It is clear from your series that $$
K_n (\rho ) = \frac{1}{2}(n - 1)!(\rho /2)^{ - n} (1 + \mathcal{O}(\rho ^2 )) + \frac{{( - 1)^{n - 1} }}{{n!}}(\rho /2)^n \log (\rho /2)(1 + \mathcal{O}(\rho ^2 )) + \mathcal{O}(\rho ^n )
$$ as $\rho \to 0+$ when $n=1,2,\ldots$ and the same but with the first term being absent when $n=0$. Now just inspect which terms dominate when $n=0$ and when $n=1,2,\ldots$. (Note that $x\log x \to 0$ when $x\to 0+$.)

Comment: why it is clear? Sorry, but it's not clear for me :( This $O$ notation is very confusing

Comment: Bad news! You will have to learn [something new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). :)

Comment: bad bad news (for me), I don't understand why the last term is $O(\rho^n)$

Comment: good news, I understood your argument, thank you very much for the help :)